Proxy config setting in angular for websocket
I have an issue to connect to WS in different domain with angular. The ws is ok, I can connect to it via postman:
The url looks like this: {{hosturlws}}/ws?station=1f51228c-25ae-47c0-965f-68025268e2a2
The host urlws is: wss://{{ourDomain}}
I can see the data in postman,
If I'M trying to connect in Angular I got error.
This is my socket:  this.socket = new WebSocket('ws?station=' + stationId);
This is my proxy config for it:
"/ws": {
        "target": "wss://{{ourDomain}}",
        "secure": false,
        "ws":true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
      },

But I get this in console:
socket.service.ts:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/ws?station=1f51228c-25ae-47c0-965f-68025268e2a2' failed: 

Do you have any advice?
I want to connect to ws in angular
